# Select2 não funciona no meu pc mas funciona no jsfidle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select, jquery-select2

[Este](https://jsfiddle.net/gsvbjnp0/) código que está no jsfidle funciona, ou seja, mostra o select estilizado e com o select com um input search.

```
    <html>
            <head>
                <title>TESTE</title>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/i18n/pt-BR.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>

                <script language="JavaScript">
                    $('.multiplo').select2({
                        placeholder: 'selecione'
                    });
                </script>

                <style type="text/css">
                    .multiplo{
                        width:50%;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>


            <body>

            <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

            <select class="multiplo" name="" multiple="multiple">
                <option>Um</option>
                <option>Dois</option>
                <option>Três</option>
                <option>Quatro</option>
            </select>



            </body>
            </html>
```

Mas quando eu pego esse código e jogo em um arquivo .php no localhost não funciona.

Como aparece quando executo no jsfidle:
[image: Execução no jsfidle]

Agora como aparece quando executo no localhost:
[image: Execução no localhost]

Alguem sabe dizer o que pode estar ocasionando isso?

Nos sources no console do chrome parece que ele carrega tanto o .css quanto o .js

[image: Source console chrome]

**EDIT**

Aba console 
[image: Aba console]

Comment: Como eu disse anteriormente, coloque o link do css dentro da tag <"head">, exclua cache(opcional) e tente novamente! No seu caso, pode ser problemas com cache que é bastante comum! Mantenha-nos informados!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só consegue aceder aos elementos da página depois de ela estar totalmente carregada.

Para isso coloque o seu código dentro de:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //aqui
});
```

Ou na sua forma mais compacta e comum:

```
$(function() {
    //aqui
});
```

Aplicando ao seu código ficaria assim:

```
$(function() {
    $('.multiplo').select2({
        placeholder: 'selecione'
    });
});
```

No JSFiddle não necessita de ter isso porque a própria plataforma executa apenas o bloco de javascript após o html e css ser carregado. O mesmo acontece nos *live snippets* do StackOverflow.

[Documentação para o document ready de JQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Poxa...isso mesmo!!!
Nem pensei nisso. 
Vlw brother!!!
O que estava ocorrendo então era que a páginas estava carregando o DOM antes de carregar os scripts .js e .css?

Comment: @L.J Ao contrario, as páginas estavam executando o js antes de carregar o DOM.

Comment: O js sempre é carregado antes do DOM ?

Comment: @L.J Depende do sitio onde se encontra na página. Normalmente se está no topo, no `<head>` então é executado antes do DOM ser carregado. Se quer ter a certeza que é executado apenas depois do DOM ser carregado tem de colocar o código dentro do *document ready* como eu indiquei.